# Async/await: do async nested functions automatically need to be awaited a level above?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have a couple questions regarding how async/await flows across levels. Some example code:

```
class Auth
  async validateJwt() { // A
    const result = await fetch(...) // #1
    return await result.json(); // #1.5
  }

  async createJwtOrValidateExisting() { // B
    const token = await validateJwt(); // #2
    return token.data;
  }
}

const auth = new Auth();

// React.js top level component
const App = props => {

  useEffect(() => { // C
    const tokenData = auth.createJwtOrValidateExisting(); // #3    
  }
}
```

Do I need to await at both steps 2 and 3?

If so, I think I need an async keyword on line C as well.

I know that await pauses execution, which is needed at the fetch() and .json() steps. In the first method this is intuitive.

But then when you await at step #2, I believe this also requires the async keyword on the higher level function, which then means a promise must be returned from it. Which seems inappropriate because the .json() step was already handled/resolved on step 1.5.

If this interpretation is not correct and I do need async/await on steps B / #2, that implies I must also turn the useEffect callback into an async function as well.

Any explanation on the proper usage of these keywords above would help a lot, thank you.

Comment: Short answer is ...yes. An `async` function always returns a promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to await at both steps 2 and 3?

For `#2`, yes. `validateJwt` is an `async` function. If you call it without an `await`, you get a promise. If you call it with an `await`, you get the resolved value of that promise.

For `#3`, `useEffect` is NOT an async function, so you must use `then` to handle the promise returned by `createJwtOrValidateExisting`. Alternatively, you can make `useEffect` an async function, and use `await` on `createJwtOrValidateExisting`.

Also, in `#1.5`, the `await` on `return await result.json()` is not necessary. `response.json()` returns a promise, which you can return immediately from an async function. See https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await

This should be:

```
class Auth
  async validateJwt() {
    const result = await fetch(...)
    return result.json()
  }

  async createJwtOrValidateExisting() {
    const token = await validateJwt()
    return token.data
  }
}

const auth = new Auth();

const App = props => {

  async useEffect(() => {
    const tokenData = await auth.createJwtOrValidateExisting()
  }
}
```

The rule of thumb is that an async function is just a function that returns a promise. If you want to extract its value without using `then`, then make the function async, and use `await` on that promise.